# How to provide a user-programmable set of validation rules

Tags: delphi, validation

I am interested in the possibility of providing a set of validation rules for user input values.

So for example a textbox called 'Today' might require a rule that looks something like

`IsADate() and (Value >= Date())`

My problem is that nobody can tell me what rules are needed.  In order to deliver a solution I need users to be able to decide for themselves what rules they want.

It occurred to me I could create a database table containing a separate field for each input - each field having a user-definable check constraint and data type, but this is too limiting (in terms of how many rules I can define)

I could allow the users a UI which would effectively allow them to provide a `where` clause which then executes a `select count(*) from dual where <plugin logic>`

And then I started to think I am just database-obsessed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Fwiw, I found that this sort of thing becomes vastly easier and more flexible if your appl has a built-in expression-evaluation engine. I generated mine using Lex+Yacc, but I think the Jedi library may have one ...

Comment: @MartynA you can use fastscript to do so in Delphi. I'd add the link here, but I can't get it to work in the comment...

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar using application code and business logic. If you create a token parser based on some of your common business objects that you can load and evaluate for various views or forms then you can start to create a collection of custom variables.

```
@Date.CurrentDate
@Date.LastQuarter
@Customer.LastInvoiceNumber
@Customer.ZipCode
@Customer.MaxNumberOfOrderItems
```

If you expose your tokens in a list of rules for a particular field you can build a custom component that will let users build expressions like.

```
Value [ Greater Than ] [ @Customer.LastOrderNumber ] [ AND ] 
Value [ Starts With  ] [ @Customer.CustomerID      ]
```

In my opinion this would be more flexible than using sql for validation.

Answer (score 3):

If users have limited of Delphi / Pascal syntax knowledge, a quick solution is to let them create the **validation as a pascal function**, and use `TJvInterpreter` from **JCL library**.

Easy to use, simple to implement, that's a good work around !

Reference:
http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/JvInterpreter.htm

Comment: +1 to this and lrb's answer.  If you don't mind me adding a suggestion, it's worthwhile interposing between your expression evaluator and the rest of the app a "TResolver" class which takes a dot-qualified name from the evaluator and looks up a corresponding value from e.g. db field names, component properties etc.  Then, you can register with the resolver any component containers you want to be look-up targets, in whatever order of precedence suits.

Comment: That is a very useful tip, thanks, I will look into it.  I doubt users' ability to provide even the most simple formulae, without a gui, though.